# Magento2 How to expand basket by default in order summary on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-summary

on checkout page, can anyone help me, how do i by default expand product in order summary.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **You can Use js mixin :-**

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
    var config = { 
            'config': {
                 'mixins': {
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items': {
                      'Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/cart-items-mixin': true
                     }
                 }  
             } 
    };
```

**Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/cart-items-mixin.js**

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isItemsBlockExpanded: function () {
            return true;
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Comment: Should this not be `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting **`openedState`** to **`active`** in your **`cart-items.html`** template.

So, override **`cart-items.html`** template from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html

To your custom module, with the same path level:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html

With this code:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
        <strong role="heading">
            <translate args="maxCartItemsToDisplay" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
            <translate args="'of'" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
            <span data-bind="text: getCartLineItemsCount()"></span>
            <translate args="'Item in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() === 1"/>
            <translate args="'Items in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() > 1"/>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content minicart-items" data-role="content" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block !important;">
        <div class="minicart-items-wrapper overflowed">
            <ol class="minicart-items">
                <each args="items()">
                    <li class="product-item">
                        <div class="product">
                            <each args="$parent.elems()" render=""/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </each>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: cartUrl}">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'View and Edit Cart'"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then create **`requirejs-config.js`** file in path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {    
   "map": {
       "*": {
           "Magento_Checkout/template/summary/cart-items.html": "Vendor_Module/template/summary/cart-items.html"
       }
   }
};
```

After doing above, redeploy static contents

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via css:

add the below css in your Magento_Checkout module less file:

```
.opc-block-summary {
   .block.items-in-cart {
     .minicart-items {
       display: block !important;
     }
     >.title {
       &:after {
         content: '\e621';
       }
     }
     &.active {
       .minicart-items {
         display: none !important;
       }
       >.title {
         &:after {
           content: '\e622';
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Great thanks... @mohammad faizan its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**In your custom css:**

```
    body.checkout-index-index .minicart-items{ 
              display:block !important; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override this file to your theme folder or write in requirejs-config.js -> magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/estimation.html

```
<div class="opc-estimated-wrapper" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
<div class="estimated-block">
    <span class="estimated-label" data-bind="i18n: 'Estimated Total'"></span>
    <span class="estimated-price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
</div>
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="action showcart" data-bind="afterRender: showSidebar" data-toggle="opc-summary">
        <span class="counter qty">
            <span class="counter-number" data-bind="text: getQuantity()"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The logic lies in changing the button's data-bind from click to afterRender so that after the page renders the function is invoked instead of click. Simple.